# Using .Between on a SearchResultItem field

Tags: content-search

I have requirements to create a search interface that allows the end user to perform faceted search against an index. One of the requirements is to be able to do a range query against certain fields (that are configured at runtime by the content owner). The search is executed as part of a REST call and the results are returned to the front end for display.

Under normal circumstances, one would do a range query using the `.Between()` method in LINQ, like so:

```
var productQuery = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
productQuery = productQuery.And(x => x[filterField].Between(lowerLimit, upperLimit, Inclusion.Both));
```

When I create the above predicate and pass it to the search context:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(string.Format(IndexBaseName, Sitecore.Context.Database.Name)).CreateSearchContext())
{
    var searchResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(productQuery).ToList(); 
}
```

The above throws a `System.NotSupportedException` with the message "Unsupported expression node type: ArrayIndex". After a bit of Googling, it appears that this might be a [limitation of LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353948/the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities), which explains why most examples of calling `.Between()` don't use `SearchResultItem` and instead use a custom model where the range field is mapped to a property. I'm my case, since the fields can vary based on how the content editor configures which fields are used for these range queries, I need to find a way around this.

Comment: Can you try the following for the predicate: `predicate.Or(x => x[filterField]).Between(lowerLimit, upperLimit, Inclusion.Both));`

Comment: That doesn't work since `.Or` is going to want a lambda function that returns a bool. Also `predicate` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in simplifying my code for posting as a question here, I left out the fact that `lowerLimit` and `upperLimit` above were actually values coming from an arrary and were actually:

```
productQuery = productQuery.And(x => x[filterField].Between(range[0],range[1], Inclusion.Both));
```

Which is the actual source of the "Unsupported expression node type: ArrayIndex" message (which is exactly the issue in the [linked Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353948/the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities).)

Comment: is this a solution to the question or an update? If its an update can you update the question, if its an answer can you clarify what the solution is please?

Comment: I had to wait in order to mark my answer my own question as accepted.